# 2 comboboxes basing a percentage

Tags: vb.net

Well 2 combo boxes and if you select either or to the dropdownlist and choose say 50, I want the other cbo to be dependent on that choice and automatically fill in the remaining (50).

Here is my code

```
Public Class 
Dim minus() As integer = {100D}
Dim answers(3) As Integer
Dim cbo() As ComboBox

Form Load;
cbo = New ComboBox() {cbopercentmain, cbopercentpro}

Private Sub cbompercentmain_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbopercentmain.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim cbo As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
        If cbo.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            answers(Array.IndexOf(comboboxes, cbo)) = 0
        Else
            answers(Array.IndexOf(comboboxes, cbo)) = CInt(cbo.Text) - minus(Array.IndexOf(comboboxes, cbo))
        End If
        cbopercentpro.Text = answers.Sum.ToString
    End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `Publis Class`.... Is this really the code you're using?  If there's a typo in one place, there's probably more in other places.  It's best to debug the actual code instead of a described approximation of it.

Comment: The ComboBoxes also have a `SelectedValue` property that could help in simplifying your code.

Comment: It was a typo, the code is the only thing I copy and pasted. Everything else looks good in the code.

Comment: I forgot to mention these are unbound. Each combobox has increments of 5 all the way to 100
cb1 - 95/cb2 - 5 etc